# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php, mysql

I have an error 
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' on line 12
at the first look everything is OK.
any ideas?

```
<?php
    require_once('include/session.inc.php');
    require_once('include/dbcon.php');

    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {

        header ('Location: /index.php');
    }
    echo $_SESSION['user_id'];


    $query = mysqli_query ($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM wants WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'";

    $minda_arr= mysqli_fetch_row ($query);


    $query=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM offer WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
    $ar_minda_arr = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

    $logo_align="1";
    ?>
```

[here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okwaO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
$query = mysqli_query ($mysqli,
            "SELECT * FROM wants WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'";
```

lacks a trailing `)`, i.e.

```
$query = mysqli_query ($mysqli,
            "SELECT * FROM wants WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
```

Comment: brrrr.... details details details.
thanks for attention

Comment: @ManueloZumbadze So you won't mind if your employer only pays you next month $300 instead of $3000? ;) I mean the extra 0 is just a detail.

Comment: :D:D right
unfortunately no one pays me... (((( nor 300 nor 3
just training